# Trying to have a header function across multiple "pages" jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using a jQuery Mobile multi-page template.

I have a header between the pages that will stay the same, however data-id isn't working to make them the same across pages (not sure why - documentation says this should work)

I am trying to have the same function affect the header the exact same in each, but there's no way to multiple ids in an HTML DOM.

For example:

```
<div class="absolute-header" data-id="main-header" data-role="header"><h1>Header Title<a href="#page-messages"><img id="mail" class="menu-mail"></a></h1></div>
```

I will have this same header on multiple pages - how should I ensure that the same block of Javascript code gets executed per jQuery Mobile page and affects a header on that page? I want to do something similar to this:

```
            if (data.data.has_mail == true) {
                var mail = document.getElementById("mail-reddit");
                mail.setAttribute("src", "orange mail.png");
            }
```

However, you can only have one id per DOM element - and that includes jQuery Mobile pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you cannot duplicate element `id`s, you have to use a `class` or (as you've already done) a custom data attribute `data-*`.

Now, use a [jQuery selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) to select your page, the header image(s) and set their source:

```
// using a class
$("#pageid .menu-mail").attr("src", "orange mail.png");

// warning: this selector updates all images in the header
$("#pageid [data-id=main-header] img").attr("src", "orange mail.png");
```

Put this code inside the `pageshow` event handler to execute it every time a page is shown:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#my_page_id", function(event, ui)
{
    // change image source
});
```

Even here you can select all your pages at once changing `#my_page_id` with `[data-role=page]`.

Comment: The first seems to work - but how do I ensure that redoes the check on each new page load (page being jQuery Mobile page load, not on an actual DOM reload, which will happen infrequently)

Comment: No, you misunderstand - on a page reload - so when I go from say, page pageid1 to page pageid2, I want this determination to run again.